# ajax - GET request keeps using same old cookie on each session

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

Here is my two ajax requests:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ",
    url: "https://example.com/j_spring_security_check",
    data: { j_username: "mmm@mmmm.com", j_password: "mmmm" },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("POST LOG IN REQUEST:\t" + request + "\nSTATUS:\t" + status + 
                  "\nERROR:\t" + error);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    },
    url: "https://mmm.com/rest/xxx/",
    success: function(output, status, xhr) {
        var flight = output;
        alert(flight[0].flight.toAirport.name);
        //return flight;
    }, 
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("GET ALL FLIGHTS REQUEST:\t" + request + "\nSTATUS:\t" + status + 
              "\nERROR:\t" + error);
    }
});
```

When I run the code and use firebug - the second request keeps using the same old cookie in every new session. What I want to happen is that the second request will use the cookie from my first POST(login) request. I have tried several variations of withCredentials: true/false and crossDomain: true/false on both requests.

When i clear the cookies, the get request will create it's own cookie. Then I refresh the page to let the script run again. The POST request will create a new cookie(as it should), but the get request will re-use the cookie it made before.